# SOAP-ENV:Server

Tags: soap, header

Hi I am having an issue with the SOAP , when I call my services I get this error:

```
  <env:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Error occured while service was processing.</faultstring>
  </env:Fault>
```

Do you know how to solve this problem then please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a symptom of one specific problem. All it says is that an "Error occured while service was processing.".

You'll have to look at any server logs to find out what error this was.